# php - IF - ELSEIF- ELSE

Tags: php

I need to create a php that generates sentence depends on what time it is. If time is 5 - 8, echo "good morning" and so on...

Here's my code

```
     <?php
  if (date('G') <= 5 - 8)
    {
     echo "Morning";
    }
  elseif (date('G') = 9 - 12) {
     echo "LOREM";
  }
  elseif (date('G') = 12) {
     echo "LOREM";
  }
  elseif (date('G') = 12 - 17) {
     echo "LOREM";
  }
  elseif (date('G') = 17 - 19) {
     echo "LOREM";
  }

  else (date('G') >= 20) {
     echo "NIGHT";
  }

  ?>
```

What's wrong _?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? Does the code not produce the output you expect? Do you get an error? Please read [ask].

Comment: `5 - 8 = -3` BTW...

Comment: `else (date('G') >= 20)` is a syntax error. Else doesn't have any condition.

Answer (score 1):

`5-8` is not "five through eight", it is "five minus eight". The `-` means subtraction. There is no "through" operator in PHP.

You had some contradictory statements in your example so mine doesn't perfectly match yours but this should point you in the right direction.

```
$hour= date('G');
if ($hour >= 5 && $hour <= 8) {
     echo "Morning";
} elseif ($hour >= 9 &&  $hour < 12) {
     echo "LOREM";
} elseif ($hour == 12) {
     echo "LOREM";
} elseif ($hour > 12 && $hour < 17) {
     echo "LOREM";
} elseif ($hour >= 17 && $hour <= 19) {
     echo "LOREM";
} elseif ($hour >= 20) {
     echo "NIGHT";
}
```

Comment: On your 2nd elseif must be: $hour == 12

Comment: @Callixor Thank you. I missed that. I probably should have written this from scratch instead of modifying the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php
if (date('G') >= 5 && date('G') <= 8)
{
 echo "Morning";
}
elseif (date('G') >= 9 && date('G') <= 11) 
{
 echo "LOREM";
}
elseif (date('G') == 12) 
{
 echo "LOREM";
}
elseif (date('G') >= 13 && date('G') <= 16) 
{
 echo "LOREM";
}
elseif (date('G') >= 17 && date('G') <= 19) 
{
 echo "LOREM";
}
elseif (date('G') >= 20) 
{
 echo "NIGHT";
}
?>
```

Comment: You should be calling `date()` every time you want to get that value. It's inefficient. Call it once and save the value to a variable.

Comment: Okay, you're right. It's just an example for him, but you we're little bit faster. ;)